# Activate Windows 10 upgrade free

Tags: windows-10-upgrade, windows-activation

I've upgraded to Windows 10 Pro using the free upgrade from Windows 8.1. 
After the upgrade, I am told to "activate windows" because "Windows isn't activated".

When I go to the settings, they ask me for a product key to activate Windows.

What can I do to fix this message?

Comment: If your Windows 8.1 was legitimate, the upgrade shouldn't require any key.  Start by calling Microsoft.  We're not going to be able to give you a key.

Comment: The best way to activate a Windows 10 installation in this state is to activate by phone.  If that isn't an option then [ShowKeyPlus](https://github.com/Superfly-Inc/ShowKeyPlus/releases) does have the capability to provide you the license key embedded in device's ACPI table.  You shouldn't have to use this tool, activating your installing by phone, is your best and quickest way to solve your problem

Comment: I had the same problem. After installing updates and restart aftere these updates has it solved.

Answer (score 1):

**@Ramhound** - you're wrong. Digital Entitlement, now called a "digital license" IS required if you want to reinstall OR if you change your hardware. If you've only got a local account (i.e. that isn't associated with your Microsoft account) then you'll be unable to activate. If you've got an account already associated then Microsoft will **automatically** associate your license to your account.

*"You’ll need to have your Microsoft account associated with your Windows 10 activation: if you log in using your Microsoft account you’re all set, but if you only used a local account, you’ll need to add a Microsoft account to Windows 10. Go to Settings > Update & security > Activation, click Add an account and complete the process."*

*"One concern that some will have is that linking installation IDs to a Microsoft account fundamentally changes the anonymity of activation. That's not likely to go over well with the contingent that believes Windows 10 telemetry is actually a secret spying program."*

Sources:

http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/55398-microsoft-account-link-digital-license-windows-10-pc.html

http://www.zdnet.com/article/microsoft-tweaks-activation-rules-for-the-windows-10-anniversary-update/

Comment: Welcome to Super User! The site's Q&A format reserves answers for solutions to the question. This post is really a comment rather than an answer. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post. Non-answers tend to attract downvotes and are subject to deletion.

Answer (score 0):

If you changed some part of your hardware and aren't connected with a Microsoft Account, it's possible that Windows will once again ask for a key, once you try to activate it. Just enter your previous Windows key (e.g. Windows 7 or 8/8.1) and it should get accepted.

Comment: What does linking your local profile to a Microsoft Account have to do withthe  activating a Windows 10 installation?  There is zero correlation between those two actions.

Comment: MS is linking product keys with Microsoft Account / hardware combinations now.

Comment: @Spivonious - You mean the digital entitelment?  You recieve a digital entitlement license even if you don't link your local account to a Microsoft Account.  *Linking your local profile to a Microsoft Account is not a requirement to activate Windows 10.*  Rumors like that makes people feel uneasy about using Windows 10.  Any additional features that comes from linking to your Microsoft Account, with regards to your license, is simply an optional feature.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I wasn't clear on how the digitial entitlement license was linked to the user. I assumed it was to the user's MS Account.

Comment: Microsoft really doesn't make anything clear in regards to Win10 upgrades.

Comment: @Ramhound No, it's no requirement, but it helps you avoiding having to reenter your key as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths - They actually do.  I have done extensive research on the subject and my information is directly from Microsoft.

Comment: @Mario - Linking to your Microsoft Account is not a requirement for Windows 10 to automatically activate on hardware its already been activated on in the past.  Feel free to provide a source for that information if you think different.

Comment: @Ramhound Personal experience. Local account only, swapped main board and CPU. Would complain about the key on activation and had to reenter the 8.1 key (which worked). Maybe it was some other thing in addition, e.g. no internet access on first boot after the change.

Comment: The reason you had problems is because you replaced the motherboard, that was to be expected, for activation purpose the motherboard is considered to be the computer

Comment: @Ramhound I'm aware that I had to reactivate. Having to enter the key again was new.

Comment: You had to enter the key again because your hardware digital entitlement wasn't valid for the new motherboard, if it was the same motherboard, it would have activated automatically